# NodeJS - find by Id not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am just starting with NodeJs, I followed a few tutorials but after I try to do it by myself I am struggling with some things.

I'm trying to edit a post saved into my Mlab (Mongo) database. But I can't reach my values even if I have a good response:

My server.js code

```
 app.get('/post/:id/edit', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.params.id)
  db.collection('posts').find({_id:ObjectId(req.params.id)},{},{}, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)
    if (err) return console.log(err)
      res.render('edit.ejs', {post: result})
  })
})
```

As a result I'm getting the below: (no text or title as expected)

```
Readable {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler:
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'analistafuncionalblog.posts',
  cmd:
   { find: 'analistafuncionalblog.posts',
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     query: { _id: 5921bf9aff2e7524b4552480 },
     readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] },
     slaveOk: true,
     fields: {} },
  options:
   { readPreference: { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] },
     skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: true,
     db:
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     disconnectHandler: { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
  topology:
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { reconnect: [Function],
        reconnectFailed: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Function],
        destroy: [Function],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverOpening: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        attemptReconnect: [Function],
        monitoring: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 17,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     id: 0,
     s:
      { options: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        Cursor: [Object],
        bson: {},
        pool: [Object],
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        monitoring: true,
        inTopology: false,
        monitoringInterval: 5000,
        topologyId: -1 },
     ismaster:
      { hosts: [Object],
        setName: 'rs-ds149221',
        setVersion: 1,
        ismaster: true,
        secondary: false,
        primary: 'ds149221-a.mlab.com:49221',
        me: 'ds149221-a.mlab.com:49221',
        electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
        maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
        maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
        localTime: Sun May 21 2017 16:50:58 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time),
        maxWireVersion: 4,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        ok: 1 },
     lastIsMasterMS: 168,
     monitoringProcessId:
      { _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 17129,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: null },
     initalConnect: false,
     wireProtocolHandler: { legacyWireProtocol: {} },
     _type: 'server',
     clientInfo:
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v4.4.7, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.10' },
     lastUpdateTime: 0,
     lastWriteDate: 0,
     staleness: 0 },
  cursorState:
   { cursorId: null,
     cmd:
      { find: 'analistafuncionalblog.posts',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        slaveOk: true,
        fields: {} },
     documents: [],
     cursorIndex: 0,
     dead: false,
     killed: false,
     init: false,
     notified: false,
     limit: 0,
     skip: 0,
     batchSize: 1000,
     currentLimit: 0,
     transforms: undefined },
  logger: { className: 'Cursor' },
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 16,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s:
   { numberOfRetries: 5,
     tailableRetryInterval: 500,
     currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
     state: 0,
     streamOptions: {},
     bson: {},
     ns: 'analistafuncionalblog.posts',
     cmd:
      { find: 'analistafuncionalblog.posts',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        slaveOk: true,
        fields: {} },
     options:
      { readPreference: [Object],
        skip: 0,
        limit: 0,
        raw: undefined,
        hint: null,
        timeout: undefined,
        slaveOk: true,
        db: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        disconnectHandler: [Object] },
     topology:
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 17,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        id: 0,
        s: [Object],
        ismaster: [Object],
        lastIsMasterMS: 168,
        monitoringProcessId: [Object],
        initalConnect: false,
        wireProtocolHandler: [Object],
        _type: 'server',
        clientInfo: [Object],
        lastUpdateTime: 0,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        staleness: 0 },
     topologyOptions:
      { host: 'ds149221.mlab.com',
        port: 49221,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        socketOptions: {},
        socketTimeout: 30000,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        bson: {} },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     currentDoc: null },
  sortValue: undefined }
```

In my Mlab I keep my collection like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5921bf9aff2e7524b4552480"
    },
    "title": "Prueba 1",
    "text": "Ezequiel prueba texto"
}
```

how can I get the title and the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collection.find()` returns a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find), which you need to read from in order to get the actual documents from the database.

For that, you can use [`cursor.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray):

```
db.collection('posts').find({
  _id : ObjectId(req.params.id)
}).toArray(function(err, results) {
  ...
});
```

However, since you're searching on a unique property (`_id`), you could also use [`collection.findOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne):

```
db.collection('posts').findOne({ _id : ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, post) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: I was also missing `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;` to mention on the top.

Comment: Brilliant! Curious that some other answers explicitly suggested passing just a string, without converting to ObjectID and it worked.

Comment: @Vaviloff to be honest, I think it'll work with strings too, but using `ObjectId` explicitly will at least catch invalid parameters being passed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Mongoose, it allows you to do a lot of useful things, and is very easy to use. In your case, you can define a schema for the db and then apply all the mongoDB query on it.

Your record.js looks like that:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Record = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    text: {type: String, required: true}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Record', Record);
```

Then in a new file, you can import the model and make all the query that you need:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Record = require('./record');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/YOURDB');

app.get('/post/:id/edit', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.params.id)
   Record.findById(req.params.id, function(err, record){
      if(err) throw err;
      else return res.render('edit.ejs', {post: result});
   });
});
```

Comment: can I use mlab with mongoose to?

Comment: @EzequielRamiro Yes, i think so. Mongoose is just a npm package.